# How do I lock my Mac and have the monitors turn off?

Tags: sleep-wake, screensaver

This has been plaguing me.

I have my Macbook Pro (Sonoma) plugged into two external monitors. When I lock or sleep my computer, it goes to the Lock Screen with all monitors on. Sometimes, the screens will go black for a few seconds, but they immediately turn back on.

Is there a key command, or a Setting, or something, that will allow me to press a button to both lock my computer and turn the screens off? I'm lighting up this room for nothing.

Comment: What model (year) is the MBP, and what make and model are the displays; and how are they connected? (E.g. cable type, hubs).

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth trying a Hot Corner.

My own Mac is set to never sleep, just to switch off the displays after some time unattended, then lock.
However, there are some apps - specifically for me Cubase - which prevent the Mac from sleeping, locking or even switching off the displays.

Hot Corners to the rescue.
System Settings > Desktop & Dock > [scroll right down] > Hot Corners…

[image]

Set to something you won't trigger accidentally - in this case it's bottom left corner, but only when also holding  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   - then whenever you want to switch off the screens, hold  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  & drag the cursor hard into the bottom left corner. This should also instantiate your sleep/lockout timer, if set.
You set a corner action *with* additional key by holding the appropriate key as you select from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Check what apps you are running, this happens to me sometimes when either:

- I am using a browser to streaming videos (YouTube, Amazon Prime, Netflix, etc).
- I have been on a Video or Audio call: Zoom, Teams, etc.

Sometimes the Mac gets confused (and thinks your are still streaming audio/video when you are not). The only option that worked for me was to close the application that the Mac thinks is still streaming.

When it's playing up, I usually have to close out said programs (Browser, Teams, or Zoom), with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> - closing out all windows with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> doesn't always work.

Further note: I had a USB graphics card driving an external monitor, this issue seemed to be more prevalent when the the video stream was on that particular monitor, so it may have been a driver issue with that USB card - anywho the fix was as described above.

Answer (score 0):

I use Alfred. With Alfred, I issue a "Sleep Display" command which does that. It can be configured in [Alfred Preferences - Features - Systems](https://alfredapp.com/help/features/system).